# how to handle onNotification event in ngCordova push plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

as a code template doing it like this,

```
.controller('PushNotificationsCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaPush) {
var androidConfig = {
"senderID":"372433177444",
"ecb":"onNotification"
};

$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
  // Success!
  $scope.pushSuccess = result
}, function(err) {
  $scope.pushSuccess = err;
});
```

I manage to successfully get an RegID from GCM. But then how do I manage `onNotification` from `androidConfig` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the solution.

instead of doing this :

```
var androidConfig = {
"senderID":"372433177444",
"ecb":"onNotification"
};
```

I do like this :

```
var androidConfig = {
"senderID":"372433177444",
"ecb":"window.onNotification"
};
```

then

```
window.onNotification = function(e) {
  switch( e.event )
  {
      case 'registered':
          if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
          {
              console.log("Your regID is : " + e.regid);
          }
          break;

      case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model     from the push server
          console.log('message = '+e.message);
          angular.element(document.querySelector('#yata')).html(e.message);
          break;

      case 'error':
          console.log('GCM error = '+e.msg);
          break;

      default:
          console.log('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
  }
};
```

all work as expected now :)

Comment: did either of you get the geoLocation plugin working?

Comment: But if you want to have access to injected dependencies like $http to send regid to my API , i suppose this solution isn't working because of "window" context ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code to `ng-cordova.js`:

```
//config.ecb = 'angular.element(' + injector + ').injector().get(\'$cordovaPush\').onNotification';
config.ecb = "angular.element(" + injector + ").injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification";
```

and then set the options configuration object as follows:

```
var options = {
  android: {
    senderID: "789175757493",
    ecb:"onNotification",
    forceShow: true
  },
}
```

It will display notifications in notification drawer when application is opened.